# Remove negative using math.abs but stripe decimal

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Math.abs(-101.2) // 101.2

but how to remove the decimal point? Should I use another Math function like round to wrap the method above?

Comment: "Should I use another Math function like round to wrap the method above?" - yes, exactly

Comment: what result do you expect?

Comment: Lets consider value `-101.9` - what value you are expecting? `101` or `102`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) to do it

```js
let x = Math.floor(Math.abs(-101.2));

console.log(x)
```

if you want to round it you can use [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

```js
let x = Math.round(Math.abs(-101.2));

console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use floor or ceil as needed.

```
var x = Math.floor(Math.abs(-101.2)); //makes x=101

var y = Math.ceil(Math.abs(-101.2)); //makes y=102
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the `Math.abs` inside a `parseInt`

```js
var a = parseInt(Math.abs(-101.2)); // 101.2
console.log(a);
```

If you want to get the rounded value, for example 102 for 101.8, use `Math.round` instead of `parseInt`.

```js
var a = Math.round(Math.abs(-101.1));
var b = Math.round(Math.abs(-101.9));
console.log(a,b);
```